# headless browsing - WWW::Mechanize and HTTP::Response

Tags: perl, http

I'm playing with `WWW::Mechanize`, i.e.

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(\%opts);
$mech->get($url);
my $reponse = $mech->follow_link(regex_url => qr/some link/);
```

`$response` is returned as an `HTTP::Response` object. My question is, can I use my `$mech` to continue to follow links in the response, submit forms, etc? What can I do with the `$response` object?

Comment: The $mech object itself has methods to do each of those things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HTTP::Response](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response) has everything you want back from the other site:

- `$response->is_success()` will tell you if the request was successful,
- `$response->code()` will return you the HTTP Response Code,
- `$response->header('Content-Type')` will return the `Content-Type` HTTP Header,
- `$response->content()` will give you the response content,
- etc.  Check out the perldoc on [HTTP::Response](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response) for more details.

As for `$mech`, you can continue to use it for links, etc.

Check out [WWW::Mechanize::Examples](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Examples) for some good examples.